# Managing UI state in Tailwind

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, use-state

I'd like to recreate an accordion component into Tailwind CSS. What is the workaround with `${active}` state of the button?

Here is the code from original component:

```
<button className={`question-section ${active}`} onClick={toggleAccordion}>
```

And here it is with Tailwind, where I have no idea where to put `${active}`:

```
<button 
  className="bg-transparent border-slate-600 rounded-lg shadow-md pointer w-screen" 
  {${active}}
  onClick={toggleAccordion}
>
```

[full code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuwZt.png)

Will appreciate, thanks ✌️

Answer (score 0):

Tailwind does not work well with dynamic values. You can instead build a CSS object and pass it in the `style` attribute of your button. You can also avoid using your `useEffect()`, since you are setting the local `active` state to drive the changes. For example, using your `active` and `contentRef` values:

```
const accordionMax = active ? `${contentRef.current.scrollHeight}px` : '0px';

...

<button 
  className='bg-transparent border-slate-600 rounded-lg shadow-md pointer w-screen'
  style={{maxHeight: accordionMax}}
  ...
>
  ...
</button>
```